# sql select statement to show results if source = B exists then results with source B otherwise results from source O

Tags: sql

I want to select the report from report source 'B' if exists, otherwise report_source 'O'

```
select r.rep_id,
       r.rep_name,
       r.rep_status,
       r.rep_source
       o.cmp_id,
       o.cmp_company_name,
       o.cmp_company_al
  from company o,
       report r
 where o.cmp_id = r.rep_cmp_id
   and r.rep_status in ('N','A')    
   and r.rep_source = ???decode;
```

output example:

> rep_id   rep_name    rep_status      rep_source    cmp_id     cmp_company_name   cmp_company_name_al
>
> 100      REP-2000    A               O             144        ASM                Assist Support Mgt
>
> 120      REP-9900    A               B             144        ASM                Assist Support Mgt

I want the results if the rport source is B. If there is no  report from this source for the company  then show the report with the report source O

so the results to be shown is in this case:

> 120      REP-9900    A               B             144        ASM                Assist Support Mgt

Comment: And what have you tried so far...?

Comment: `r.rep_source ='B' or r.rep_source ='O'`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you: (When you want to select char 'B' in rep_source when it is present else 'O'. Go with below code.)

```
select r.rep_id,
       r.rep_name,
       r.rep_status,

       CASE WHEN r.rep_source = 'B' THEN 'B' ELSE 'O' END AS rep_source

       o.cmp_id,
       o.cmp_company_name,
       o.cmp_company_al
  from company o,
       report r
 where o.cmp_id = r.rep_cmp_id
   and r.rep_status in ('N','A')
```

Else if you want to get rep_source with 'B' or 'O' values. Go with this:

```
     select r.rep_id,
           r.rep_name,
           r.rep_status,
           r.rep_source,
           o.cmp_id,
           o.cmp_company_name,
           o.cmp_company_al
      from company o,
           report r
     where o.cmp_id = r.rep_cmp_id
       and r.rep_status in ('N','A')
       and r.rep_source ='B' or r.rep_source ='O'
```

Comment: I want the results if the report source is B. If there is no  report from this source for the company  then show the report with the report source O